# column value is showing string while some are actual is integer. how can change integer in integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have hug data where in one column like emp_code is some are starting 2 and some are starging l(L). when i am read.csv it is showing all value in string format.
I  want that integer should be in integer.

1. `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')` - first try
2. `df["new"] = df['Agency FOS'].str.split(expand=True,)` - second try

```
ABC = []    
for row in df["New"] :
        if row == "I": ABC.append (row.value)
        else : ABC.append ((row.value) * 1)
df["ABC"] = ABC
```

234567 = 23567 (data type should be integer)

i2345 = i2345  (data type should be string)

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Pandas all values in a column have the same type. So your column can be of an `int` type or it can be of type `object`.
You can help yourself in two ways:

1. you use object to store the column and convert the single values in the column, that are integers to integer.
2. you can split the data across two columns, one for `int` and one for `str`.

I'd prefer the second one, but that depends, on what you plan to do with your data. I would prefer it, because, what do you gain from having some of the values as `int`, if it is hard to calculate on the column?

Here is how both variants would work. First I define a test dataframe and an indexer, that identifies all `int` values, or better, all values, that do not start with an ell. The indexer is then used in both variants:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(dict(mixed_col=['l123', '23422', '8343', 'l2232']))
indexer= ~df['mixed_col'].str.startswith('l')
# a maybe safer variant for an indexer would be
indexer= ~df['mixed_col'].str.isnumeric()

# variant 1
df.loc[indexer, 'mixed_col']= df.loc[indexer, 'mixed_col'].map(int)

# variant 2: first create an empty new column with nullable INTSs, then
#            set the values in it, which represent INTs in mixed_col
df['int_col']= pd.Series([None]*df.shape[0], index=df.index, dtype='Int64')
# note the lower case int64 instead of Int64
# for Int64 I got an conversion error
# Int64 is relatively new in Pandas, so you maybe need
# need to update your pandas version.
# Please see below (***), in case you need to do this with an 
# older version of pandas, that doen't support Int64
df.loc[indexer, 'int_col']= df.loc[indexer, 'mixed_col'].astype('int64')
```

The type of the data in the original column has types:

```
>>> df['mixed_col'].map(type)
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: mixed_col, dtype: object
```

The result of the first variant looks like:

```
>>> df['mixed_col'].map(type)
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: mixed_col, dtype: object
```

The result of the second variant looks like:

```
>>> df
  mixed_col  int_col
0      l123      NaN
1     23422    23422
2      8343     8343
3     l2232      NaN

>>> df.dtypes
mixed_col    object
int_col       Int64
dtype: object
```

Btw. if you need to do it in combination with `read_csv` and you decide to use variant 1, you can do it either in a post processing step, as described above, or you can create your own conversion function and pass it as a converter to `read_csv`. It would look like

```
df= pd.read_csv(filename, ..., converters={'mixed_col': lambda v: int(v) if v.isnumeric() else v})
```

`***` If you need to implement a kind of variant 2 with an old version of pandas, it gets a bit more complicated. You would have to use an int default value for all rows where there your column value starts with `l` (ell) and probably have to introduce an indicator column which tells you which of the values was really converted from the string and which not.
E.g. by storing the indexer in a separate column and call it something like 'is_numeric'. Maybe that already convinced you to update pandas, if you haven't already done so :-)

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your support but when i am trying to use this, i am getting below error "
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'I12787' "